# How to use bouncycastle to generate certificate private key with DES-EDE3-CBC

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I want to use java to generate the certificate programmably. The private key of the certificate requires DES-EDE3-CBC, the private key example show below.  How can I use the bouncycastle to generate the private key like that?

Current My enviornment: JDK 8 and BC 1.55

[image: example private key]

Comment: DES-EDE3-CBC is the encryption used to protect the private key. Generate a password-protected private key and you're done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encrypt a private key with Password using BouncyCastle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597371/encrypt-a-private-key-with-password-using-bouncycastle)